# Differential Equation Constants and Singular Solutions

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, singular-solution

In my Differential Equations class, we began to learn about singular solutions. As I understand, a singular solution of a differential equation (DE) is a solution that cannot be achieved by setting the constant *C*.

This is my understanding:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = (y-3)^2 $$
We separate the DE:
$$ \frac{1}{(y-3)^2}dy = dx $$
Integrate:
$$ \int{\frac{1}{(y-3)^2}dy} = \int{dx}$$
$$ \frac{-1}{y-3} = x + C $$
Solve for *y*:
$$ y = 3 - \frac{1}{x+C} $$

In the original DE, $y =3$ is a solution. However, there is no possible value for $C$ that would lead to this solution. As a result, this is a singular solution.

In class, we were given the following DE and asked to identify possible singular solutions:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{6y}{x} $$
We separate and integrate:
$$ \int \frac 1 y dy = 6 \int \frac 1 x dx $$
$$ \ln|y| = 6\ln|x| + C_1 $$
Solve for $y$:
$$ y = e^{C_1}x^6 $$
$e^{C_1}$ is a new numerical constant and becomes $C$:
$$ y = Cx^6 $$

My professor said that at first glance of the original DE $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{6y}{x}$, $y = 0$ could be a singular solution (he makes singular solutions in the class turn out to be constants). However, he said that since $C$ could be equal to $0$, $y=0$ is *not* a singular solution.

So my question is this:

If the original constant of integration was $C_1$, and the new constant of integration $C = e^{C_1}$, how is it possible that $C = 0$ when $e^x$ is never equal to $0$? Is $y = 0$ a singular solution?

Can the newly derived constant $C$ take on *any* value, despite its origin?

Answer (score 1):

In your second displayed equation, you have divided by $(y-3)^2$.  Whenever you divide by a variable quantity you have to split into two cases.  Either 1. $y-3 \neq 0$ and so we can divide by it, or 2.  $y-3=0$ and we have to deal with that case. The second case gives $y=3$ as a solution, and there is no $C$ in this case.

Comment: So y=3 is a singular solution, since it was eliminated as a solution during the division process? If that's the case, can the C in my second DE be 0?

Comment: There's some confusion here between $y=0$ and $y=3$.  $y=0$ is not a solution at all.  $y=3$ is a solution.  There is more than one way to be singular and sometimes it depends on prof and/or text, but technically, a solution is "singular" if it breaks either existence or uniqueness.  The problem here is going to be uniqueness.  Can we choose an initial condition $(x_0,y_0)$ through which there are multiple solutions?  How about $(1,3)$.  This forces $C=3$ in your first solution, so $y=3x^6$ passes through the point.  But so does $y=3$.  So it's a singular solution.